# Node.js: How to send control C to child process

Tags: bash, node.js, terminal, control-characters

I am writing one web-like linux shell using node.js + socket.io. Simple command like, ls, cd are working well.
But when issue command like ping google.com, the stdout is printing endlessly. 
I tried to send Ctrl +C to stdin, but no luck.

1) spawn 'bash' process

```
spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var sh = spawn('bash');
```

2) send bash stdout to socket.io

```
sh.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
   console.log('stdout' + data);
   listener.sockets.emit("stdout",new Buffer(data));
});
```

3) Sending Ctl C (\x03) to bash's stdin. 
    var listener = io.listen(server);

```
listener.set('log level',1);
listener.sockets.on('connection', function(client){
   client.on('message', function(data){
      if(data === "KILL") {
         console.log('!!!!' + data);
         sh.stdin.write('\x03');
         client.broadcast.send(new Buffer("KILLING "));
         //return;
      };
      console.log(data);
      sh.stdin.write(data+"\n");
      client.broadcast.send(new Buffer("> "+data));
   });
});
```

I am stuck at this point. Seems like

Answer (score 1):

Try `process.kill(sh.pid)`. I use this to kill workers in a cluster when my master process shuts down. `sh.signalCode` should be equal to `SIGTERM`. Of course, I have no idea if this works on Windows.

Comment: Should be `process.kill(sh.pid, 'SIGINT');`

Comment: The default is SIGTERM on OS X. I imagine the terminate or interrupt call is OS dependent.

Answer (score 0):

try `stdout.push(null)`.
I tried it on node 12. This will not kill your child process instead it will tell you output stream that there is no more input stream.