# I want to send a CTRL + C command to client how can I achieve this in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, ssh2-sftp, node.js-client

**My Code Looks Like this**

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
var fs=require('fs');
var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function() {
    console.log('Client :: ready');
    conn.shell('xtail', function(err, stream) {
        stream.write('xtail\n\r');
        if (err) throw err;
        stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
            console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
            conn.end();
        }).on('data', function(data) {
           // stream.stdin.write('?');
            console.log('hey');
            console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
            fs.appendFile('D:\\Breme\\As1.txt',data,function(err){
                if(err)
                {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                //console.log('file saving..')
            });
            // setTimeout(function(){
            //     process.exit(1);
            // }, 20000);
        }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
            conn.destroy();

        });
    });
}).connect({
    host: '10.214.14.15',
    port: 22,
    username: 'bwadn',
    password: 'bwain'
});
```

*after connecting to server I am downloading the file but I want to send 'Ctrl+C' command from client, so that it stops receiving data*

**Can anyone please help me in solving this, As i am new to NodeJS I need your support in solving this...thanks**

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696967/node-js-how-to-send-control-c-to-child-process

Comment: @AliNiaz i am unable follow it can you please help little more ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js: How to send control C to child process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696967/node-js-how-to-send-control-c-to-child-process)

Answer (score 0):

Most reliable way in this particular case, since you are using a variant of `tail` in your shell, is to use

```
 stream.write('\x03'); //send ctrl+c
```

you would need to send it when you know you don't need `xtail` output anymore. It is beyond the scope of this question to discuss the means, but `setTimeout` is definitely not a good idea.

Alternative (preferred) method:

```
stream.signal('INT')
```

and for other uses see [Ssh2 Channel API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2#channel)